# How to write an app to altering Windows8 login options?

Tags: api, authentication, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm looking to write an app that disallows some of the password login options (picture pw or  pin) at certain moments - for myself and security reasons.

Any ideas how one would go about finding the APIs to use that can be run when the computer is locked and disallow a specific login option ?

I checked all classes under Windows.Security.Authentication, Windows.System.UserProfile, and Windows.System.Profile, but didn't see anything to toggle those login options. There are method to set the bg pic under Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen, but that isn't what i'm looking for - just the ability to toggle the picture pw and pin options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter the login process I believe you have to implement your own custom credential provider. There is a sample in the Windows SDK on how to do this.

You can find more info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).